# Redirecionar para outra ação de outro controller no Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud, rails4

Estou a desenvolver uma ação simples, ao salvar um cadastro se existir valor em um determinado campo o sistema deve redirecionar para um create de outro modelo/controller. Estou com problemas para fazer isto acontecer

```
   if @reproduction.update(reproduction_params)
    if reproduction_params[:parturition].nil?
      format.html { redirect_to reproductions_path, notice: I18n.t('crud.saved') }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @reproduction }
      format.js { render 'reproduction', animal: @animal, reproductions: @reproductions }
    else
      @animal = Animal.new(@reproduction)
      redirect_to new_animal_path
    end
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @reproduction.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    format.js { render 'edit' }
  end
end
```

A ideia é que ao salvar o estado da gestação, se há parto após salvar o usuário seja direcionado para o cadastro de novo animal. E se possível já selecionado em qual gestação ele foi gerado (desta forma podemos rastrear os pais e outras variáveis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vejo duas formas de resolver seu problema, vai depender da estrutura de seu projeto.

A primeira seria fazer um render da outra action, assim você poderá utilizar sua variável `@animal`

```
(...)
else
  @animal = Animal.new(reproduction_id: @reproduction.id)
  render 'animals/new'
end
(...)
```

A segunda seria fazer o redirect e mandar via params as informações que você deseja que já fique preenchida no form, então receber e preencher isso do outro lado.

```
(..)
else
  redirect_to new_animal_path(reproduction_id: @reproduction.id)
end
(...)
```

Comment: Para ambos os casos está retornando a seguinte mensagem:

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 92ms (ActiveRecord: 74.9ms)

ArgumentError - When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.:

Comment: @AndréGava opa, vi agora que você está passando `@reproduction` como parâmetro para Animal.new, você deve passar um hash com os atributos de animal. Como eu não conheço a estrutura não posso te dizer com certeza quais são. Quais os atributos do model Animal?

Comment: Editei, a segunda forma não deve reproduzir o erro. E a primeira precisa ser verificada qual é o campo certinho.

Comment: Tentei das duas formas, aparentemente estamos tendo progresso, parou de dar erro, por exemplo:
@animal = Animal.new(reproduction_id: @reproduction.id)
          format.html {render 'animals/new', notice: I18n.t('crud.saved') }
Não acusa erro no terminal. Porém tem um detalhe não está saindo da tela, o form anterior está sendo carregado via ajax (partial), e eu quero redirecionar para uma página nova (detalhe estou usando turbo links).

Comment: Então pro seu caso vai ser a segunda forma, pegue os parâmetros da requisição na sua action e faça todos os tratamentos. Não tem como ajudar muito mais que isso, pois você apresentou uma visão limitadíssima de seu problema.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37492886/after-submitting-a-remote-form-with-rails-how-do-i-redirect-the-user-to-another

Como o form era via ajax tive que fazer assim, mas o redirect to funciona onde a requisição é via html normal